# iterate the rows and join in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

i have master dataset like this

```
master = pd.DataFrame({'Channel':['1','1','1','1','1'],'Country':['India','Singapore','Japan','United Kingdom','Austria'],'Product':['X','6','7','X','X']})
```

[image: master]

and user table like this

```
user = pd.DataFrame({'User':['101','101','102','102','102','103','103','103','103','103'],'Country':['India','Brazil','India','Brazil','Japan','All','Austria','Japan','Singapore','United Kingdom'],'count':['2','1','3','2','1','1','1','1','1','1']})
```

[image: user]

i wanted master table left join with user table for each user. like below for one user

```
   merge_101 = pd.merge(master,user[(user.User=='101')],how='left',on=['Country'])
   merge_102 = pd.merge(master,user[(user.User=='102')],how='left',on=['Country'])
   merge_103 = pd.merge(master,user[(user.User=='103')],how='left',on=['Country'])
   merge_all = pd.concat([merge_101, merge_102,merge_103], ignore_index=True)
```

how to iterate each user here i am first filtering the dataset and creating another data set and appending the whole data set later.

is there any better way to do this task like for loop or any joins?

Thanks

Comment: Can you copy and paste the dataframes instead of the images? Others can simply copy and use the dataframes to understand the problem. Also, Can you show your current vs expected output? I do not see a need to loop.

Comment: sure will add data frames in a while

Comment: @HarvIpan added dataframes

Comment: Can you show your expected output? Your code has `Userid` column but your dataframe does not have a `Userid` column.

Comment: @HarvIpan added some more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you need:

```
pd.concat([pd.merge(master,user[(user.User==x)],how='left',on=['Country']) for x in list(user['User'].unique())], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
    Channel         Country Product User count
0        1           India       X  101     2
1        1       Singapore       6  NaN   NaN
2        1           Japan       7  NaN   NaN
3        1  United Kingdom       X  NaN   NaN
4        1         Austria       X  NaN   NaN
5        1           India       X  102     3
6        1       Singapore       6  NaN   NaN
7        1           Japan       7  102     1
8        1  United Kingdom       X  NaN   NaN
9        1         Austria       X  NaN   NaN
10       1           India       X  NaN   NaN
11       1       Singapore       6  103     1
12       1           Japan       7  103     1
13       1  United Kingdom       X  103     1
14       1         Austria       X  103     1
```